# Download animation popup iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, download, popup

For my application I am downloading some data, how could I get a nice downloading popup with animation and without button that will go away automatically when download is finished.

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MBProgressHUD:

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Of course show/hide of it depends on your app logic.

Answer (score 0):

use     UIProgressView  and set UIProgressViewInst.progress = so_far_downloaded/total_download.

Keep updating the progress value as download progresses and hide it once download is finished.

```
thumbs_download_progress = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 120, 200, 50)];
thumbs_download_progress.progressViewStyle = UIProgressViewStyleDefault;
thumbs_download_progress.progress = 0.0f;
[self addSubview:thumbs_download_progress];
```

Comment: You may wrap this small piece of code in a view and add activity indicator or small semi black transparent background to to make it look nice.